# Alogrithm in using perl to find the value in array - Absolutely Interview Questions

Tags: algorithm, perl

I am asked to do the perl program to find a value(from user input) in array. If matched "its ok". If not matched, then check within the value in the index[0] to index[1] ... index[n]. So then if the value matched to the between two elements then report which is near to these elements might be index[0] or index[1].

Let you explain.

Given array : `10 15 20 25 30`;
Get the value from user  : 14 (eg.)

Hence 14 matched with in the two elements that is 10(array[0]) - 15(array[1])

> Ultimately the check point is do not use more than one `for` loop and never use the `while` loop. You need to check one `for` loop and many of `if` conditions.

I got the output by which I did here is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr1 = qw(10 15 20 25 30);
my $in = <STDIN>;
chomp($in);

if(grep /$in/, @arr1)
{  } #print "S: $in\n";  }
else
{
    for(my $i=0; $i<scalar(@arr1); $i++)
    {
        my $j = $i + 1;
        if($in > $arr1[$i] && $in < $arr1[$j])
        {
            #print "SN: $arr1[$i]\t$arr1[$j]\n";
            my ($inc, $dec) = "0";

            my $chk1 = $arr1[$i] + 1;
            AGAIN1:
            if($in == $chk1)
            { }
            else
            {  $chk1++; $inc++; goto AGAIN1;  }

            my $chk2 = $arr1[$j] - 1;
            AGAIN2:
            if($in == $chk2){ }
            else
            {  $chk2--;  $dec++; goto AGAIN2;  }
            if($inc > $dec)
            {  print "Matched value nearest to $arr1[$j]\n";  }
            elsif($inc < $dec)
            {  print "Matched value nearest to $arr1[$i]\n";  }
        }
    }
}
```

However my question is there a way in algorithm?. Hence if someone can help on this one and it would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're looking to work as a perl programmer...

Comment: Fortunately I am a perl programmer. But Unfortunately I don't know how to do this in algorithm.

Comment: I don't think you are a Perl programmer. Why are you using `lt` and `gt` instead of `<` and `>`?

Comment: @DaveCross: Believe me. Not lie. Sometimes I made a mistake chilly.

Comment: @ssr1012: I agree with **Dave Cross**. A Perl programmer would not use a C-style `for` loop or an `if` condition with an empty block. I also doubt if the question intends you to avoid `while` loops by constructing them out of labels and `goto`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem determined to make this as complicated as possible :-)

Your specification isn't completely clear, but I think this does what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @array = qw[10 15 20 25 30];

chomp(my $in = <STDIN>);

if ($in < $array[0]) {
  say "$in is less than first element in the array";
  exit;
}

if ($in > $array[-1]) {
  say "$in is greater than last element in the array";
  exit;
}

for (0 .. $#array) {
  if ($in == $array[$_]) {
    say "$in is in the array";
    exit;
  }

  if ($in < $array[$_]) {
    if ($in - $array[$_ - 1] < $array[$_] - $in) {
      say "$in is closest to $array[$_ - 1]";
    } else {
      say "$in is closest to $array[$_]";
    }
    exit;
  }
}

say "Shouldn't get here!";
```

Comment: Yes. I know I created with more complexity. But you awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Using the helper functions `any` and `reduce` from the core module [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) and the built in `abs`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/reduce any/;

my @arr1 = qw(10 15 20 25 30);

chomp(my $in = <STDIN>);

if (any {$in == $_} @arr1) {
    print "$in is in the array\n";  
}
else {
    my $i = reduce { abs($in - $arr1[$a]) > abs($in - $arr1[$b]) ? $b : $a} 0 .. $#arr1;
    print "$in is closest to $arr1[$i]\n";  
}
```